# The value of the local variable 'userId' isn't used. (dart unused_local_variable)

Tags: dart, flutter

Am getting the below problem. Can I get help in this in solving this issue.

[image: Please click the below image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As said by the error, you're not using the variable `userId`

Comment: "https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-user-login-with-firebase-a6af760b14d5", from here am trying this example @Remi Rousselet.   But the variable is used..

Comment: Your code is different from the one in the article.

Comment: I downloaded it from the GIT link, which he gave there.

Comment: If your variable is used, could you show us where?